# Torcc file settings MacOS for a Relay doesn't work

Tags: relays, mac

I use the Tor Browser on my MacOS-Sierra. Am not automatic now a Relay I read. But when I change the torcc file the browser doesn't start anymore.

An answer would be great, or also the right configuration marks in torcc file for the relay to get started in MacOS-sierra.

Thanks, Boaz

Answer (score 1):

There is an official way to run a relay on OS X, but warning: It can get messy!

First, you will need to install Homebrew. Instruction at https://brew.sh/, or run the following command in Terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Once that command finishes, run the following command in terminal

```
brew install tor
```

Once that finishes, Terminal might ask you to patch it or something by running a certain command, which I had to. Use the commands Terminal will give you to patch whatever it says to. Once that is done, on the OS X menu bar click Go -> Go To Folder and go to  /usr/local/etc/tor/. There will be a file called "torrc.sample" Open this file. At the bottom of the page, type in this information:

```
Nickname enter-a-name-for-your-tor-relay
ORPort enter-a-port-number-here
ExitPolicy 0
ControlSocket 0
ContactInfo enter-an-email-address
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

Keep in mind, the port number you choose next to ORPort needs to be configured for port forwarding on your router and firewalls if you have any. Also the email address you put will be publicly listed on your relay information in the tor network, however I'd recommend using one that works as tor will send an email to this address if the relay is not working correctly, etc.

Unfortunately the things you have to run and patch in terminal can get a little messy. Let me know how it goes buddy.

Answer (score 0):

No, using Tor Browser does not automatically turn your computer into a relay. Instructions on how to create a relay are here, but they suggest an OS other than MacOS.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en

Comment: Yes I've tried this settings, but them my Tor Browser will not startup. Can somebody give me the right settings for MacOS-Sierra? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a little like you want to run a relay and use Tor browser at the same time. Tor doesn't recommend you do both from the same computer simultaneously as they can interact in unexpected ways that could compromise the security of either service.

If you want to be able to run one or the other at your discrection at different times from the same computer, I recommend storing them in different locations (eg. you should not use the same torrc file for both your bridge and your browser)